# How to develop a Content Management system(CMS) from Elastic search indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case that I need to develop a Content Management system(CMS) from Elastic search indexes. 
This is to have a dashboard of elastic search indexes which should be able to edit and save. I don't want a chart Web UI like Kibana. Any suggestions?

Comment: use jQuery  it solves all problem

Comment: Thanks, @VolodymyrBilyachat. Would I be able to edit the index from Web UI and sync back the index?

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Why not to use any existing open source?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat could you give an example? what exactly did you mean?